# R: Substituting character strings coerced from numbers in scientific notation with gsub

Tags: regex, r

I need to export som data to a text file in another programming language where the numbers can't exceed 14 digits. Not all elements need to be comma seperated so this is why I use this method.

The problem is that `gsub` doesn't reconize the number 42 when coerced to a character string and the scientific notation option `scipen` is set low enough, so 42 gets printed in E-notation.

Here `scipen=-10` so 42 is printed in E-notation.

```
x <- 4.2e+1    # The meaning of life
options(scipen = -10) 
gsub(pattern=x,replacement=paste(",",x),x,useBytes=TRUE)
[1] "4.2e+01"
gsub(pattern=x,replacement=paste(",",x),x,useBytes=FALSE)
[1] "4.2e+01"
```

It is like gsub doesn't reconize the match. I have also tried,

```
gsub(pattern=x,replacement=paste(",",x),as.character(x))
```

but with no luck.

In the following two examples `gsub` acts as expected, and the `scipen=0` is high enough to ensure 42 is printed as `42`.

```
x <- 4.2e+1    # Still the meaning of life
options(scipen = 0) 
gsub(pattern=x,replacement=paste(",",x),x,useBytes=TRUE)
[1] ", 42"
gsub(pattern=x,replacement=paste(",",x),x,useBytes=FALSE)
[1] ", 42"
```

As you can see the `useBytes` option doens't help either. Can someone please tell me what I am not getting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters `.` and `+` are predefined regex characters. Hence, they are not interpreted literally. You have to escape these characters in your pattern (with `\\`). Then, it will work.

```
x <- 4.2e+1    # The meaning of life
options(scipen = -10) 

x_pat <- gsub("(\\+|\\.)", "\\\\\\1", x)
# [1] "4\\.2e\\+01"

gsub(x_pat, paste(",", x), x)
# [1] ", 4.2e+01"
```

Another possibility is to use the argument `fixed = TRUE`. This matches the pattern string as is.

```
gsub(x, paste(",", x), x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] ", 4.2e+01"
```